# Does jest-each provide a way to get more access to the passed arguments in the test description?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Given this sample test using TypeScript and Jest based on https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout

```
  it.each([
    { numbers: [1, 2, 3] },
    { numbers: [4, 5, 6] }
  ])('Test case %#: Amount is $numbers.length => $numbers', ({ numbers }) => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

The test runner only prints

> ✓ Test case 0: Amount is $numbers.length => $numbers (4ms)

Is there a way I can replace `$numbers` with its value and work with it? E.g. calling array functions on it.

---

A working alternative would be

```
  [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ].forEach((numbers, index) => {
      it(`Test case ${index}: Amount is ${numbers.length} => ${numbers}`, () => {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
      })
  });
```

but I don't know if this is the suggested way.

Comment: All the options for each's name are listed in https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout. Just use regular JS - `[...].forEach((numbers) => it(...))`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the template literal implementation of `test.each`, e.g.:

```js
test.each`
    input | expectation
    ${1}  | ${'expected-1'}
    ${2}  | ${'expected-2'}
    ${3}  | ${'expected-3'}
`('When the input=$input should return $expectation', ({ input, expectation }) => { ...
```

Note a couple of things about this:

1. As it's a template literal, you need to enter the values in the table wrapped in `${ }`.
2. You need to format the table carefully with `|` to delimit the columns
3. The arguments need to be destructured in the test callback ( `{ input, expectation}` instead of `input, expectation`)